# Validating XML against XSD using PL SQL

Tags: xml, oracle, validation, plsql, xsd

I'm attempting this project where I have an Oracle database in which I store XML and XSD in separate tables. Both tables have a xmltype column that contains the document (I'm using Oracle 11g xe with XML DB).

The idea is having a function that validates one XML against one of schemas in a function and returns true or false depending on the result of the validation, but I have no clue how to approach this.

I've been doing some research at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb08tra.htm#i1026778 without much success, as all the explanations assume the schema is in the local file system, not in a table in my database. Also, when explaining the XMLIsValid function they talk about a XML Instance and I'm not sure I understand what they mean by that or how to do it (I've just started learning PL SQL and I'm not confident at all using it).

The XML and the schema are very simple examples from W3schools for the moment, as the content of the document is not as important to me right now as to finding out how to make the validation work.

Can anyone show me an example of how it could be done? Also, any lead or clue would help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following example:

1. you need to register schema.
2. you need to get both file and schema.
3. use xmlisvalid as the function to check validity

   ---

   ```
    DECALRE

    registered_ NUMBER;
    data_  CLOB;
    schema_ CLOB;
    xml_    XMLTYPE;
    valid_  NUMBER;

    CURSOR get_schema_ IS
       SELECT content 
       FROM schema_table_
       WHERE file_name = 'schema_name_';

    CURSOR get_file_ IS
       SELECT content 
       FROM file_table_
       WHERE file_name = 'file_name_';

    CURSOR check_register IS
       SELECT COUNT(schema_url) 
       FROM user_xml_schemas  
       WHERE schema_url = 'file_name_';

    BEGIN

       OPEN get_data;
       FETCH get_data INTO schema_; 
       CLOSE get_data;

       OPEN check_register;
       FETCH check_register INTO registered_;
       CLOSE check_register;

       IF registered_ = 0 THEN
          DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.registerSchema(schemaurl       => file_name_, 
                                        schemadoc       => schema_,
                                        local           => TRUE,
                                        gentypes        => FALSE,
                                        gentables       => FALSE,
                                        enablehierarchy => 
       DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.enable_hierarchy_none);   
       END IF;

       OPEN get_file_ ;
       FETCH get_file_ INTO data_;
       CLOSE get_file_ ;

       xml_ := xmltype(data_, file_name_);

       SELECT XMLISVALID(xmltype(data_), file_name_) AS is_valid 
       INTO valid_ 
       FROM dual;

       IF valid_ = 0 THEN
          dbms_output.put_line('In Valid');
       ELSE
          dbms_output.put_line('Valid');
       END IF;   
    END;
   ```